# git merge --continue without opening editor

Tags: git, merge, editor

I'm working on a script that goes through a number of git operations. There was a `git merge` failure. On the merge operation, I provided the text message with `-m`. If, after taking care of the conflicts, I run `git merge --continue`, I get to see an editor and I'm able to see the lines that I used on the first merge operation so that I can edit them. Now, what I want to do is run `git merge --continue` but I also want git to allow the message that I used originally for the revision. If I tried with `git merge --continue --no-edit` it fails miserably:

```
$ git merge --continue --no-edit
fatal: --continue expects no arguments

usage: git merge [<options>] [<commit>...]
   or: git merge --abort
   or: git merge --continue
.
.
.
```

I then tried setting the message again:

```
$ git merge --continue -m "BLAH"
fatal: --continue expects no arguments

usage: git merge [<options>] [<commit>...]
   or: git merge --abort
   or: git merge --continue
.
.
.
```

So, how can I run `git merge --continue` skipping the text editor altogether and accepting the original comment?

Comment: Either cheat (run `git commit` instead of `git merge --continue`), or cheat (set the editor to a does-nothing-and-succeeds command, e.g., `GIT_EDITOR=true git merge --continue`).

Comment: Right.... was able to pull it off with `-c core.editor`. Were you waiting for me to post the question? :-D

Answer (score 14):

After a few attempts I was able to do it by setting `core.editor` to `/bin/true`:

```
git -c core.editor=/bin/true merge --continue
```

Should also work like this:

```
GIT_EDITOR=/bin/true git merge --continue
```

Comment: Works also for rebase. 
May be shortened: `git -c core.editor=true rebase --continue`

Comment: Only the second form worked for me.

"-c core.editor=/bin/true" did not show any argument errors, so it seems to have parsed correctly. But it still popped up an interactive editor.

Answer (score 3):

As Junio Hamano says in his first reply to [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/all/xmqqk0ft5toy.fsf@gitster.g/T/), the recommended way to achieve this is to run `git commit --no-edit` at that point (instead of `git merge --continue`):

> The way to finish a conflicted merge has always been to run "git
> commit" before "merge --continue" was added, and it still is not
> just accepted but is the right way to finish a conflicted merge.
>
> ...
>
> In fact, "merge --continue --no-edit" is much longer to type than
> "commit --no-edit".

Comment: In case you don't recognize the name and need to look it up (like I did), Junio Hamano is the maintainer of git.